# How to make UITableView section headers like in CoreDataBooks?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been wondering how to implement UITableView section headers like in Apple's example application [CoreDataBooks](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2). Please take a look at this video:

[video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzK5IffHgFg)

1. Such a header looks different from ordinary headers. I've never seen such a header before.
2. When you scroll the table the header isn't moving up until it's being pushed from underneath by the next header.

I went through each line of CoreDataBooks code and i can't find what makes headers look and behave the way they do. The only thing i was able to find is if you return empty string from method `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` then (instead of empty headers as i expected) there are no headers at all. Any suggestions? How do i do that?

Comment: This is the default behavior in UITableViewStylePlain.

Comment: If you use UITableViewStyleGroup - you headers will move "under" the top. If you use UITableViewStylePlain - behavior like on video is default. And headers are default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that has want, but it seems that they use a custom section view. You can obtain this result by implement the UITableViewDelegate "viewForHeaderInSection"

An exemple of use :

```
-(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Header image have the same heigth that section 
    UIImageView *letterUIImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<header image>]];

    UILabel *letterUILabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 3, 300, 18)] autorelease];

    [letterUIImageView setAlpha:0.5];

    [letterUILabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [letterUILabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [letterUILabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size: 14.0f]]; 
    [letterUIImageView addSubview:letterUILabel];

    [letterUILabel setText:[self titleForHeaderInSection:section]];

    return  letterUIImageView;
}
```